# Codeigniter reformating POST data after form validation

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a problem and I can't imagine how this is going on. So I run form_validation to validate my form inputs. After that, `$_POST['user_name']` becomes array instead of string.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'Vartotojo vardas',
        'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]|alpha_dash|callback_checkUserNameUnique');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'El. pašto adresas',
        'trim|required|valid_email|callback_checkEmailUnique');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Slaptažodis',
        'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[60]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password_2', 'Slaptažodžio pakartojimas',
        'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[60]|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Telefono numeris',
        'trim|required|callback_checkIfPhoneGood');

    $this->setFormMessages();


    if ( $this->form_validation->run() == false ) {
        $data['json'] = array(
            'failed' => true,
            'errors' => $this->form_validation->error_array()
        );
    } else {
        print_r($_POST['user_name']);
        print_r($this->input->post('user_name', true));
    }
```

before launching `$this->form_validation->run()` and printing `$_POST['user_name']` it returns string, after `$this->form_validation->run()` it returns empty array.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

my checkUserNameUnique method:

```
function checkUserNameUnique($userName)
{
    return $this->cache->model('system_model', '_getCustomTableData', array(
        'users', array(array('user_name' => strtolower($userName))), 'id DESC', FALSE, 1
    ), CACHE_USER_CHECK_INFO_TIME);
}
```

Comment: Maybe your callback checkUserNameUnique is causing the issues?  Did you try removing this?

Comment: God, thanks. But I'm not sure why there is a problem. Added code of function.

Comment: Well remove `|callback_checkUserNameUnique` first and determine if that is your problem.  Otherwise, this function is calling another model so I still have no idea what it is doing.

Comment: @Devon yes, there was a problem. But I don't get it why, there is only a callback for check. Thanks for help, changed method actions and the problem gone.

Comment: Don't know how, but now is not working, I've deleted my answer. So what could be wrong with that method?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know what CI's callbacks are supposed to return.  Are they supposed to return a validated value or are they supposed to return a boolean?

Comment: Callback's are supposed to return true or false. But there is no logic with that POST value reset

Comment: `Callback's are supposed to return true or false.`I am not suire. what's about `trim` ?

Comment: Callbacks or not, all rules may act in one of two ways - validate or modify. If the function/rule returns boolean, it validates; in any other case, it modifies the original input - that's how `trim` works too.

Answer (score 1):

`_getCustomTableData` returns an array, so change your callback function like this:

```
function checkUserNameUnique($userName)
{
    if (empty($this->cache->model('system_model', '_getCustomTableData', array(
        'users', array(array('user_name' => strtolower($userName))), 'id DESC', FALSE, 1
        ), CACHE_USER_CHECK_INFO_TIME)))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_unique', 'The %s field must be unique.');
        return FALSE;
    }    
}
```

Form validation also supports checking uniqueness:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name', 'Vartotojo vardas',
    'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[30]|alpha_dash|is_unique[users.user_name]');
```